# How to stop camera flash when triggering autofocus?

Tags: android, android-camera, camera-api

In my camera app, I'm triggering an autofocus when the user taps the screen, using this code:

```
mCamera.autoFocus(null);
```

I'm also allowing the user to set the camera flash mode in an options screen. The problem is that when triggering an autofocus the camera flash sometimes triggers on some phones, and users are complaining about this. On most of these phones, this can be avoided by setting the flash mode to `Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF`. I have verified this on a Galaxy S2, but on some phones (e.g. Nexus 4) it still happens even then (according to user reports).

How can I reliably prevent the camera flash light turning on when triggering an auto-focus? Is it possible?

Comment: How did you solve this issue?

Comment: Is this issue fixed?

Comment: @PandiriDeepak No I never managed to find a solution for all devices

Comment: @samgak : How you fixed then? This is really a big headache :(

Comment: @PandiriDeepak I didn't fix it. The behaviour seems to be part of the camera driver on some phones and you can't change it, as far as I know. If I knew the solution I would self-answer.